# Meteor: How do I save to a collection and getdata out of it?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am trying to make two function. 
Save() should check if there is an existing document for that user, and if there is then update his save with a new one, and if there is not then insert a new doc using the user's unique id as the docs unique id.
Load() should check if there is an existing save with the user's Id and load it.
I am purely new to that and here is the error I get

> Uncaught Error: Not permitted. Untrusted code may only update
>   documents by ID. [403]

I get that it happens because of how update and insert work. But I want to use the user's unique iD for documents, because it looks simple.

```
function Save() {
        if (Meteor.userId()) {
            player = Session.get("Player");
            var save = {    
                    id: Meteor.userId(),
                    data = "data"
                    };
            console.log(JSON.stringify(save));
                if (Saves.find({id: Meteor.userId()})){
                    Saves.update( {id: Meteor.userId()}, {save: save} )
                    console.log("Updated saves")
                }
                else {
                    Saves.insert(save)
                }

            console.log("Saved");
            }
}

function Load(){
        if (Meteor.userId()){
            if (Saves.find(Meteor.userId())){
                console.log(JSON.stringify(Saves.find(Meteor.userId()).save.player));
                player = Saves.find(Meteor.userId()).save.player;
                data= Saves.find(Meteor.userId()).save.data

            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects/documents `id`-field is called `_id`.
[See here!](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_collection)

The error occurs when you try the update of the existing object/document on the client side.
You always need to pass in the objects `_id` to update the object/document from client code.
Note that you always try to pass an `id` not an `_id`!

So try it like this:

```
function Save() {
    if (Meteor.userId()) {
        player = Session.get("Player");
        var save = {    
                _id: Meteor.userId(),
                data = "data"
                };
        console.log(JSON.stringify(save));
            if (Saves.find({_id: Meteor.userId()})){
                Saves.update( {_id: Meteor.userId()}, {save: save} )
                console.log("Updated saves")
            }
            else {
                Saves.insert(save)
            }

        console.log("Saved");
        }
}
```

Also note that your `Load()` function could work, because `Collection.find()` uses the string you pass as an `_id` for the document.

Hope that helped!